# Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML elements with same name but different attribute values to different class members

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to parse XML that has several "Fields" elements to different class members according to one of their attributes.
Here is the XML:

```
<Series>
    <Fields type="SelectedFields" operation="SUM">
        <Field name="Remaining" />
        <Field name="Invested" />
    </Field>
    <Fields type="FirstSelectedFields" operation="SUM">
        <Field name="Estimated" />
    </Field>
</Series>
```

And here is the java class it should be mapped to:

```
public class APMSeries {

    private List<Field> selectedFields;

    private List<Field> firstSelectedFields;

}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I set the Fields element with attribute type="SelectedFields" to the selectedFields member and the Fields element with the attribute type="FirstSelectedFields" to the firstSelectedFields member?

Comment: What does the XML look like if you add a second selected field?

Comment: I cannot add another Fields element with the attribute type="SelectedFields" again. I can only place it once. And if I want to have several fields, I add them as "Field" elements under it (as in the above example, I updated it).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class APMSeries {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="SelectedFields")
    private List<Field> selectedFields;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="FirstSelectedFields")
    private List<Field> firstSelectedFields;

}
```

Comment: I think i misread your question. The above answer may not work. SelectedFields and FirstSelectedFields are types and not names