# Map XML with same element and attribute names to Java object

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, mapping

I already searched for this particular issue, the closest thread i found was this one: [Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML elements with same name but different attribute values to different class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078479/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-elements-with-same-name-but-different-attribute-values) But it's still not exactly what i need, so i hope someone can help me with this.

I am doing a SOAP request on a Zimbra Collaboration Suite 7 Server to get a contact. The response is something like this:

```
<cn fileAsStr="Arthur, Spooner" f="" id="280" rev="1973" d="1338524233000" t="" md="1338524233" ms="1973" l="7"><meta/><a n="homePostalCode">93849</a><a n="lastName">Spooner</a><a n="birthday">1980-05-24</a><a n="homeStreet">Berkleystreet 99</a><a n="firstName">Arthur</a></cn>
```

I want to map this to a Java object, something like this:

```java
public class Contact {
Integer id;
Integer rev;
String namePrefix;
String firstName;
String middleName;
String lastName;
String jobTitle;
ArrayList<Adress> adresses;
Date birthday;
String department;
Integer mobilePhone;
String email;
String company;
String notes;
    ...
```

I usually do this using JAXB, but as all the elements are called a and all the attributes n, I don't know how to map this. I really would appreciate a code snippet or any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ContactAttribute {

    @XmlAttribute(name="n")
    private String attribute;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "cn")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Contact {

    @XmlAttribute
    Integer id;

    @XmlAttribute
    Integer rev;

    //...

    @XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "a"))
    List<ContactAttribute> attributes;
    //...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Castor Mapping](http://www.castor.org/how-to-map-a-hashtable.html) 
it will help you to Marshall and Unmarshall the data.

Comment: Any reason for -1 .Please addcomment.

Comment: -1 for not explaining how Castor can be used to solve the specific problem identified in the question.

Comment: You go through the URL the tutorial is self explained.Where it is saying How to convert XML2Java or Java2XML.

Comment: See section "Provide Context for Links":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: It's is clearly written that you can use it for Marshalling and Unmarshalling the data.

Comment: The question is about how to map a specific use case, not a general question about converting data to/from XML.  If you update the answer to include how it solves the specific question I will remove the down vote.